# Display a message box with a timeout value

Tags: excel, vba, winapi, messagebox, wsh

The question comes from code like this.

```
Set scriptshell = CreateObject("wscript.shell")
    Const TIMEOUT_IN_SECS = 60
    Select Case scriptshell.popup("Yes or No? leaving this window for 1 min is the same as clicking Yes.", TIMEOUT_IN_SECS, "popup window", vbYesNo + vbQuestion)
        Case vbYes
            Call MethodFoo
        Case -1
            Call MethodFoo
    End Select
```

This is a simple way to display a message box with a timeout from VBA (or VB6).

In Excel 2007 (apparently also happens in Internet Explorer at times) the popup window will not timeout, and instead wait for user input.

This issue is tough to debug as it only happens occasionally and I do not know the steps to reproduce the issue. I believe it to be an issue with Office modal dialogs and Excel not recognising the timeout has expired.

See http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ITCG/thread/251143a6-e4ea-4359-b821-34877ddf91fb/

The workarounds I found are:

A. Use a Win32 API call

```
Declare Function MessageBoxTimeout Lib "user32.dll" Alias "MessageBoxTimeoutA" ( _
ByVal hwnd As Long, _
ByVal lpText As String, _
ByVal lpCaption As String, _
ByVal uType As Long, _
ByVal wLanguageID As Long, _
ByVal lngMilliseconds As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" ( _
ByVal lpClassName As String, _
ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long

Public Sub MsgBoxDelay()
    Const cmsg As String = "Yes or No? leaving this window for 1 min is the same as clicking Yes."
    Const cTitle As String = "popup window"
    Dim retval As Long
    retval = MessageBoxTimeout(FindWindow(vbNullString, Title), cmsg, cTitle, 4, 0, 60000)

    If retval <> 7 Then
        Call MethodFoo
    End If

End Sub
```

B. Use a manual timer with a VBA userform that is designed to look like a messagebox. Use a global variable or similar to save any state that needs to be passed back to the calling code. Ensure that the Show method of the userform is called with the vbModeless parameter supplied.

C. Wrap the call to wscript.popup method in the MSHTA process which would allow the code to run out of process and avoid the modal nature of Office.

```
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "mshta.exe vbscript:close(CreateObject(""WScript.Shell"").Popup(""Test"",2,""Real%20Time%20Status%20Message""))"
```

What is the best way of A, B or C or your own answer to display a message box with a timeout value in VBA?

Comment: Not sure what your question is ... but the win32 API solution looks ok to me.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear enough. I thought the questions first two sentences clarified it. I will re-edit it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Going with Answer A.  the Win32 solution. This meets the requirements, and is robust from testing so far.

```
Declare Function MessageBoxTimeout Lib "user32.dll" Alias "MessageBoxTimeoutA" ( _ 
ByVal hwnd As Long, _ 
ByVal lpText As String, _ 
ByVal lpCaption As String, _ 
ByVal uType As Long, _ 
ByVal wLanguageID As Long, _ 
ByVal lngMilliseconds As Long) As Long 

Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" ( _ 
ByVal lpClassName As String, _ 
ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long 

Public Sub MsgBoxDelay() 
    Const cmsg As String = "Yes or No? leaving this window for 1 min is the same as clicking Yes." 
    Const cTitle As String = "popup window" 
    Dim retval As Long 
    retval = MessageBoxTimeout(FindWindow(vbNullString, Title), cmsg, cTitle, 4, 0, 60000) 

    If retval <> 7 Then 
        Call MethodFoo 
    End If 

End Sub
```

Comment: You could have used a generic APC `SetTimer()` call and pop up a msgbox in the callback.

Answer (score 11):

This is a long answer, but there's a lot of ground to cover: it's also a late reply, but things have changed since some of the replies to this (and similar questions) have been posted on the stack. That sucks like a vacuum cleaner on triple-phase AC, because they were good answers when they were posted and a lot of thought went into them.

The short version is: **I noticed that the Script WsShell Popup solution stopped working for me in VBA a year ago, and I coded a working API timer callback for the VBA MsgBox function.**

Skip straight to the code under the heading **VBA code to call a Message Box with a Timeout** if you need an answer in a hurry - and I did, I have literally thousands of instances of a self-dismissing 'MsgPopup' substitute for VBA.MsgBox to redact, and the code below fits into a self-contained module.

However, the VBA coders here - myself included - need some explanation as to why perfectly good code no longer seems to work. And if you understand the reasons, you may be able to use the partial workaround for 'Cancel' dialogs, buried in the text.

I noticed that the Script WsShell Popup solution stopped working for me in VBA a year ago - The 'SecondsToWait' timeout was being ignored, and the dialog just hung around like the familiar VBA.MsgBox:

```
MsgPopup = objWShell.PopUp(Prompt, SecondsToWait, Title, Buttons)
```

And I think I know the reason why: you can no longer send a WM_CLOSE or WM_QUIT message to a dialog window from anywhere other than the thread which opened it. Likewise, the User32 DestroyWindow() function will not close a dialog window unless it's called by the thread that opened the dialog.

Someone in Redmond doesn't like the idea of a script running in the background and sending a WM_CLOSE commands to all those essential warnings that halt your work (and, these days, making them go away permanently needs local admin privileges).

I can't *imagine* who would write a script like that, it's a terrible idea!

There are consequences and collateral damage to that decision: WsScript.Popup() objects in the single-threaded VBA environment implement their 'SecondsToWait' timeout using a Timer callback, and that callback sends a WM_CLOSE message, or something like it... Which is ignored in most cases, because it's a callback thread, not the owner thread for the dialog.

You *might* get it to work on a popup with a 'CANCEL' button, and it'll become clear why that is in a minute or two.

I've tried writing a timer callback to WM_CLOSE the popup, and that failed for me, too, in most cases.

I've tried some exotic API callbacks to mess with the VBA.MsgBox and WsShell.Popup window, and I can tell you now that that they didn't work. You can't work with what isn't there: those dialog windows are very simple and most of them don't contain any functionality, at all, except for the responses in the button clicks - Yes, No, OK, Cancel, Abort, Retry, Ignore, and Help.

'Cancel' is an interesting one: it appears that you get a freebie from the primitive Windows API for built-in dialogs when you specify `vbOKCancel` or `vbRetryCancel` or  `vbYesNoCancel`  - the 'Cancel' function is automatically implemented with a 'close' button in the dialog's Menu bar (you don't get that with the other buttons, but feel free to try it with a dialog containing 'Ignore'), which means that....

#### WsShell.Popup() dialogs will sometimes respond to the SecondsToWait timeout if they have a 'Cancel' option.

```
objWShell.PopUp("Test Me", 10, "Dialog Test", vbQuestion + vbOkCancel)
```

That might be a good enough workaround for someone reading this, if all you wanted was to get WsShell.Popup() functions to respond to the SecondsToWait parameter again.

This also means that you can send WM_CLOSE messages to the 'Cancel' dialog using the SendMessage() API call on a callback:

```
SendMessage(hwndDlgBox, WM_CLOSE, ByVal 0&, ByVal 0&)
```

Strictly speaking, this should only work for the `WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_CLOSE` message - the 'close' box in the command bar is a 'system' menu with a special class of commands but, like I said, we're getting freebies from the Windows API.

I got that to work, and I started thinking: *If I can only work with what's there, maybe I'd better find out what's actually there*...

And the answer turns out to be obvious: Dialog boxes have their own set of WM_COMMAND message parameters -

```
' Dialog window message parameters, replicating Enum vbMsgBoxResult:
CONST dlgOK      As Long = 1
CONST dlgCANCEL  As Long = 2
CONST dlgABORT   As Long = 3
CONST dlgRETRY   As Long = 4
CONST dlgIGNORE  As Long = 5
CONST dlgYES     As Long = 6
CONST dlgNO      As Long = 7
```

And, as these are the 'user' messages which return the user responses to the caller (that is to say, the calling thread) of the dialog, the dialog box is happy to accept them and close itself.

You can interrogate a dialog window to see if it implements a particular command and, if it does, you can send that command:

```
If GetDlgItem(hWndMsgBox, vbRetry) <> 0 Then
    SendMessage hWndMsgBox, WM_COMMAND, vbRetry, 0&
    Exit For
End If
```

The remaining challenge is to detect a 'Timeout' and intercept the returning Message Box response, and substitute our own value:  -1 if we're following the convention established by the `WsShell.Popup()` function. So our 'msgPopup' wrapper for a Message Box with a timeout needs to do three things:

1. Call our API Timer for the delayed dismissal of the dialog;
2. Open the message Box, passing in the usual parameters;
3. Either: Detect a timeout and substitute the 'timeout' response...
   ...Or return the user response to the dialog, if they responded in
   time

Elsewhere, we need to declare the API calls for all this, and we absolutely **must** have a Publicly-declared 'TimerProc' function for the Timer API to call. That function has to exist, and it has to run to 'End Function' without errors or breakpoints - any interruption, and the API Timer() will call down the wrath of the operating system.

### VBA code to call a Message Box with a Timeout:

```
Option Explicit
Option Private Module  

' Nigel Heffernan January 2016 

' Modified from code published by Microsoft on MSDN, and on StackOverflow: this code is in  ' the public domain.  
' This module implements a message box with a 'timeout'  
' It is similar to implementations of the WsShell.Popup() that use a VB.MessageBox interface
' with an additional 'SecondsToWait' or 'Timeout' parameter.  

Private m_strCaption As String 

Public Function MsgPopup(Optional Prompt As String, _
                         Optional Buttons As VbMsgBoxStyle = vbOKOnly, _
                         Optional Title As String, _
                         Optional SecondsToWait As Long = 0) As VbMsgBoxResult  

' Replicates the VBA MsgBox() function, with an added parameter to automatically dismiss the message box after n seconds
' If dismissed automatically, this will return -1: NOT 'cancel', nor the default button choice.  

Dim TimerStart As Single  

If Title = "" Then
    Title = ThisWorkbook.Name
End If  

If SecondsToWait > 0 Then
    ' TimedmessageBox launches a callback to close the MsgBox dialog
    TimedMessageBox Title, SecondsToWait
    TimerStart = VBA.Timer
End If   

MsgPopup = MsgBox(Prompt, Buttons, Title)    
If SecondsToWait   > 0 Then
    ' Catch the timeout, substitute -1 as the response
    If (VBA.Timer - TimerStart) >= SecondsToWait Then
        MsgPopup = -1
    End If
End If  

End Function   

Public Function MsgBoxResultText(ByVal MsgBoxResult As VbMsgBoxResult) As String  
' Returns a text value for the integers returned by VBA MsgBox() and WsShell.Popup() dialogs  
' Additional value: 'TIMEOUT', returned when the MsgBoxResult = -1  ' All other values return the string 'ERROR'    
On Error Resume Next    

If (MsgBoxResult >= vbOK) And (MsgBoxResult <= vbNo) Then
    MsgBoxResultText = Split("ERROR,OK,CANCEL,ABORT,RETRY,IGNORE,YES,NO,", ",")(MsgBoxResult)
ElseIf MsgBoxResult = dlgTIMEOUT Then
    MsgBoxResultText = "TIMEOUT"
Else
    MsgBoxResultText = "ERROR"
End If  

End Function
'
'
'
'
'
'
'
'
'
'
Private Property Get MessageBox_Caption() As String
    MessageBox_Caption = m_strCaption
End Property  

Private Property Let MessageBox_Caption(NewCaption As String)
    m_strCaption = NewCaption 
End Property    

Private Sub TimedMessageBox(Caption As String, Seconds As Long)
On Error Resume Next

    ' REQUIRED for Function msgPopup
   ' Public Sub  TimerProcMessageBox  MUST EXIST  
    MessageBox_Caption = Caption  
    SetTimer 0&, 0&, Seconds * 1000, AddressOf TimerProcMessageBox  
    Debug.Print "start Timer " & Now  

End Sub  

#If VBA7 And Win64 Then     ' 64 bit Excel under 64-bit windows   
                            ' Use LongLong and LongPtr    

    Public Sub TimerProcMessageBox(ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, _
                                   ByVal wMsg As Long, _
                                   ByVal idEvent As LongPtr, _
                                   ByVal dwTime As LongLong)
    On Error Resume Next  

    ' REQUIRED for Function msgPopup
    ' https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/desktop/ms644907(v=vs.85).aspx  
    ' Closes a dialog box (Shell.Popup or VBA.MsgBox) having a caption stored in MessageBox_Caption
    ' This TimerProc sends *any* message that can close the dialog: the objective is solely to close
    ' the dialog and resume the VBA thread. Your caller must detect the expired TimerProc interval
    ' and insert a custom return value (or default) that signals the 'Timeout' for responses.  
    ' The MsgPopup implementation in this project returns -1 for this 'Timeout' 

    Dim hWndMsgBox As LongPtr   ' Handle to VBA MsgBox 

    KillTimer hWndMsgBox, idEvent  
    hWndMsgBox = 0
    hWndMsgBox = FindWindow("#32770", MessageBox_Caption)  

    If hWndMsgBox   <  > 0 Then  
        ' Enumerate WM_COMMAND values
        For iDlgCommand = vbOK To vbNo
            If GetDlgItem(hWndMsgBox, iDlgCommand)   <> 0 Then
                SendMessage hWndMsgBox, WM_COMMAND, iDlgCommand, 0&
                Exit For
            End If
        Next iDlgCommand  
    End If 

    End Sub  

#ElseIf VBA7 Then    ' 64 bit Excel in all environments  
                     ' Use LongPtr only   

    Public Sub TimerProcMessageBox(ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, _
                                   ByVal wMsg As Long, _
                                   ByVal idEvent As LongPtr, _
                                   ByVal dwTime As Long)
    On Error Resume Next     

    ' REQUIRED for Function msgPopup
    ' https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/desktop/ms644907(v=vs.85).aspx  
    ' Closes a dialog box (Shell.Popup or VBA.MsgBox) having a caption stored in MessageBox_Caption
    ' This TimerProc sends *any* message that can close the dialog: the objective is solely to close
    ' the dialog and resume the VBA thread. Your caller must detect the expired TimerProc interval
    ' and insert a custom return value (or default) that signals the 'Timeout' for responses.      
    ' The MsgPopup implementation in this project returns -1 for this 'Timeout' 

    Dim hWndMsgBox  As LongPtr          ' Handle to VBA MsgBox

    Dim iDlgCommand As VbMsgBoxResult   ' Dialog command values: OK, CANCEL, YES, NO, etc  
    KillTimer hwnd, idEvent  
    hWndMsgBox = 0
    hWndMsgBox = FindWindow("#32770", MessageBox_Caption)  

    If hWndMsgBox   <  > 0 Then  
        ' Enumerate WM_COMMAND values 
        For iDlgCommand = vbOK To vbNo
            If GetDlgItem(hWndMsgBox, iDlgCommand)   <> 0 Then
                SendMessage hWndMsgBox, WM_COMMAND, iDlgCommand, 0&
                Exit For
            End If
        Next iDlgCommand  
    End If  

    End Sub  

#Else    ' 32 bit Excel   

    Public Sub TimerProcMessageBox(ByVal hwnd As Long, _
                                   ByVal wMsg As Long, _
                                   ByVal idEvent As Long, _
                                   ByVal dwTime As Long)
    On Error Resume Next  

    ' REQUIRED for Function msgPopup  
    ' The MsgPopup implementation in this project returns -1 for this 'Timeout'  

    Dim hWndMsgBox As Long    ' Handle to VBA MsgBox  

    KillTimer hwnd, idEvent  
    hWndMsgBox = 0
    hWndMsgBox = FindWindow("#32770", MessageBox_Caption)  

    If hWndMsgBox   <  > 0 Then  
        ' Enumerate WM_COMMAND values 
        For iDlgCommand = vbOK To vbNo
            If GetDlgItem(hWndMsgBox, iDlgCommand)   <> 0 Then
                SendMessage hWndMsgBox, WM_COMMAND, iDlgCommand, 0&
                Exit For
            End If
        Next iDlgCommand  
    End If  

    End Sub  

#End If
```

And here are the API declarations - note the conditional declarations for VBA7, 64-Bit Windows, and plain-vanilla 32-bit:

```
' Explanation of compiler constants for 64-Bit VBA and API declarations :
' https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee691831(v=office.14).aspx

#If VBA7 And Win64 Then     ' 64 bit Excel under 64-bit windows ' Use LongLong and LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" _
                                    (ByVal lpClassName As String, _
                                     ByVal lpWindowName As String) As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" _
                                    (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, _
                                     ByVal wMsg As Long, _
                                     ByVal wParam As Long, _
                                     ByRef lParam As Any _
                                     ) As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetTimer Lib "user32" _
                                    (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, _
                                     ByVal nIDEvent As LongPtr, _
                                     ByVal uElapse As Long, _
                                     ByVal lpTimerFunc As LongPtr _
                                     ) As Long
     Public Declare PtrSafe Function KillTimer Lib "user32" _
                                    (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, _
                                     ByVal nIDEvent As LongPtr _
                                     ) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetDlgItem Lib "user32" _
                                    (ByVal hWndDlg As LongPtr, _
                                     ByVal nIDDlgItem As Long _
                                     ) As LongPtr

#ElseIf VBA7 Then           ' VBA7 in all environments, including 32-Bit Office  ' Use LongPtr for ptrSafe declarations, LongLong is not available

    Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" _
                                    (ByVal lpClassName As String, _
                                     ByVal lpWindowName As String) As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" _
                                    (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, _
                                     ByVal wMsg As Long, _
                                     ByVal wParam As Long, _
                                     ByRef lParam As Any _
                                     ) As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetTimer Lib "user32" _
                                    (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, _
                                     ByVal nIDEvent As Long, _
                                     ByVal uElapse As Long, _
                                     ByVal lpTimerFunc As LongPtr) As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function KillTimer Lib "user32" _
                                    (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, _
                                     ByVal nIDEvent As Long) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetDlgItem Lib "user32" _
                                    (ByVal hWndDlg As LongPtr, _
                                     ByVal nIDDlgItem As Long _
                                     ) As LongPtr
#Else
    Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" _
                            (ByVal lpClassName As String, _
                             ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
    Private Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" _
                            (ByVal hwnd As Long, _
                             ByVal wMsg As Long, _
                             ByVal wParam As Long, _
                             ByRef lParam As Any _
                             ) As Long
    Private Declare Function SetTimer Lib "user32" _
                            (ByVal hwnd As Long, _
                             ByVal nIDEvent As Long, _
                             ByVal uElapse As Long, _
                             ByVal lpTimerFunc As Long) As Long
    Public Declare Function KillTimer Lib "user32" _
                            (ByVal hwnd As Long, _
                             ByVal nIDEvent As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function GetDlgItem Lib "user32" _ 
                             (ByVal hWndDlg, ByVal nIDDlgItem As Long) As Long
#End If

Private Enum WINDOW_MESSAGE
    WM_ACTIVATE = 6
    WM_SETFOCUS = 7
    WM_KILLFOCUS = 8
    WM_PAINT = &HF
    WM_CLOSE = &H10
    WM_QUIT = &H12
    WM_COMMAND = &H111
    WM_SYSCOMMAND = &H112
End Enum

' Dialog Box Command IDs - replicates vbMsgBoxResult, with the addition of 'dlgTIMEOUT'
Public Enum DIALOGBOX_COMMAND
    dlgTIMEOUT = -1
    dlgOK = 1
    dlgCANCEL = 2
    dlgABORT = 3
    dlgRETRY = 4
    dlgIGNORE = 5
    dlgYES = 6
    dlgNO = 7
End Enum
```

A final note: I would welcome suggestions for improvement from experienced MFC C++ developers, as you are going to have a much better grasp of the basic Windows message-passing concepts underlying a 'Dialog' window  - I work in an oversimplified language and it is likely that the oversimplifications in my understanding have crossed the line into outright errors in my explanation.

Comment: Found this answer extremely useful. I've implemented this into my projects. I also "noticed that the Script WsShell Popup solution stopped working for me in VBA a year ago" as well, I'm only just now going thru and updating my code. Hate when things just stop working, but so glad I decided to search for a solution.

Comment: Nice post, but I have found that Microsoft gets us again.  Recently they started flagging any VBA code with DECLARES as a security risk.  There are ways for IT to deal with exceptions, but that is messy.  I will try using a non-modal dialog for these, and then poll.

Comment: @Tuntable   You do have ptrSafe in that DECLARE ?

Comment: @Tuntable - Also, can you tell us a bit more about your operating environment and your version of MS-Office?  This sounds like a misguided genius with a Sysadmin badge setting a policy on the user profile.

Comment: Nothing to do with PtrSafe.  But a lot to do with misguided Sysadmins.  But also, there has been a recent change from Microsoft, I think they disable or at least make it easy to disable any VBA with a DECLARE statement.  That said, I think I can get it done with a non-modal dialog and a bit of hackery.

Answer (score 2):

Easy

```
Call CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Popup("Timed message box", 1, "Title", vbOKOnly)
```

Comment: umm ...The problem is that.... the popup window will unexpectantly NOT timeout

Also if you examine the code in the question you will note that my code is almost exactly the same as what you presented above.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with the samples in this post my final code is as follows:

```
' Coded by Clint Smith
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' tMsgBox Function (Timered Message Box)
' By Clint Smith, clintasm@gmail.com
' Created 04-Sep-2014
' Updated for 64-bit 03-Mar-2020
' This provides an publicly accessible procedure named
' tMsgBox that when invoked instantiates a timered
' message box.  Many constants predefined for easy use.
' There is also a global result variable tMsgBoxResult.
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''


Public Const mbBTN_Ok = vbOKOnly                       'Default
Public Const mbBTN_OkCancel = vbOKCancel
Public Const mbBTN_AbortRetryIgnore = vbAbortRetryIgnore
Public Const mbBTN_YesNoCancel = vbYesNoCancel
Public Const mbBTN_YesNo = vbYesNo
Public Const mbBTN_RetryCancel = vbRetryCancel
Public Const mbBTN_CanceTryagainContinue = &H6
Public Const mbICON_Stop = vbCritical
Public Const mbICON_Question = vbQuestion
Public Const mbICON_Exclaim = vbExclamation
Public Const mbICON_Info = vbInformation
Public Const mbBTN_2ndDefault = vbDefaultButton2
Public Const mbBTN_3rdDefault = vbDefaultButton3
Public Const mbBTN_4rdDefault = vbDefaultButton4
Public Const mbBOX_Modal = vbSystemModal
Public Const mbBTN_AddHelp = vbMsgBoxHelpButton
Public Const mbTXT_RightJustified = vbMsgBoxRight
Public Const mbWIN_Top = &H40000                        'Default

Public Const mbcTimeOut = 32000
Public Const mbcOk = vbOK
Public Const mbcCancel = vbCancel
Public Const mbcAbort = vbAbort
Public Const mbcRetry = vbRetry
Public Const mbcIgnore = vbIgnore
Public Const mbcYes = vbYes
Public Const mbcNo = vbNo
Public Const mbcTryagain = 10
Public Const mbcContinue = 11

Public Const wAccessWin = "OMain"
Public Const wExcelWin = "XLMAIN"
Public Const wWordWin = "OpusApp"

Public tMsgBoxResult As Long

#If VBA7 Then

  Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" _
    (ByVal lpClassName As String, _
    ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long

  Public Declare PtrSafe Function tMsgBoxA Lib "user32.dll" Alias "MessageBoxTimeoutA" ( _
    ByVal hwnd As Long, _
    ByVal lpText As String, _
    ByVal lpCaption As String, _
    ByVal uType As Long, _
    ByVal wLanguageID As Long, _
    ByVal lngMilliseconds As Long) As Long

#Else

  Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" _
    (ByVal lpClassName As String, _
    ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long

  Public Declare Function tMsgBoxA Lib "user32.dll" Alias "MessageBoxTimeoutA" ( _
    ByVal hwnd As Long, _
    ByVal lpText As String, _
    ByVal lpCaption As String, _
    ByVal uType As Long, _
    ByVal wLanguageID As Long, _
    ByVal lngMilliseconds As Long) As Long

#End If

Public Sub tMsgBox( _
    Optional sMessage As String = "Default: (10 sec timeout)" & vbLf & "Coded by Clint Smith", _
    Optional sTitle As String = "Message Box with Timer", _
    Optional iTimer As Integer = 10, _
    Optional hNtype As Long = mbBTN_Ok + mbWIN_Top, _
    Optional hLangID As Long = &H0, _
    Optional wParentType As String = vbNullString, _
    Optional wParentName As String = vbNullString)

    tMsgBoxResult = tMsgBoxA(FindWindow(wParentType, wParentName), sMessage, sTitle, hNtype, hLangID, 1000 * iTimer)
End Sub
```

Comment: +1 for the effort and because it works. But I find the time resolution of 1 sec is too large, shoudl be 1/10, and more generally the parameters should be the same as the regular MsgBox, in order to allow fast replacement.

Comment: @PatrickHonorez Thanks!  I will update this later for exactly that!  Appreciate the feedback and yes it does work I have used this in Word, Excel, and Access.  Also the resolution can be changed by editing the last line. :D

Comment: Hi, how would I use this code in my VBA?  
   

answer = tMsgBox(which parameters????)
   

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Declare Function MsgBoxTimeout _
     Lib "user32" _
     Alias "MessageBoxTimeoutA" ( _
         ByVal hwnd As Long, _
         ByVal MsgText As String, _
         ByVal Title As String, _
         ByVal MsgBoxType As VbMsgBoxStyle, _
         ByVal wlange As Long, _
         ByVal Timeout As Long) _
    As Long
    Dim btnOK As Boolean
    Dim btnCancel As Boolean
    Dim MsgTimeOut As Boolean

Option Explicit

Sub Main

    AutoMsgbox("Message Text", "Title", vbOkCancel , 5) '5 sec TimeOut

    MsgBox("Pressed OK: " & btnOK & vbNewLine & "Pressed Cancel: " & btnCancel & vbNewLine &"MsgBox Timeout: " & MsgTimeOut)

End Sub

Function AutoMsgbox(MsgText , Title , MsgBoxType , Timeout)

    Dim ReturnValue
    Dim TimeStamp As Date
    TimeStamp = DateAdd("s",Timeout,Now)
    Dim MsgText1 As String

    Dim TimeOutCounter As Integer

    For TimeOutCounter = 0 To Timeout

        MsgText1 = MsgText & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & " Auto Selction in " & Timeout - TimeOutCounter & " [s]"

        ReturnValue =  MsgBoxTimeout(0 , MsgText1 , Title, MsgBoxType, 0 ,1000)

        Select Case ReturnValue
            Case 1
                btnOK       = True
                btnCancel   = False
                btnAbort    = False
                btnRetry    = False
                btnIgnore   = False
                btnYes      = False
                btnNo       = False
                MsgTimeOut  = False
                Exit Function
            Case 2
                btnOK       = False
                btnCancel   = True
                btnAbort    = False
                btnRetry    = False
                btnIgnore   = False
                btnYes      = False
                btnNo       = False
                MsgTimeOut  = False
                Exit Function
            Case 3
                btnOK       = False
                btnCancel   = False
                btnAbort    = True
                btnRetry    = False
                btnIgnore   = False
                btnYes      = False
                btnNo       = False
                MsgTimeOut  = False
                Exit Function
            Case 4
                btnOK       = False
                btnCancel   = False
                btnAbort    = False
                btnRetry    = True
                btnIgnore   = False
                btnYes      = False
                btnNo       = False
                MsgTimeOut  = False
                Exit Function
            Case 5
                btnOK       = False
                btnCancel   = False
                btnAbort    = False
                btnRetry    = False
                btnIgnore   = True
                btnYes      = False
                btnNo       = False
                MsgTimeOut  = False
                Exit Function
            Case 6
                btnOK       = False
                btnCancel   = False
                btnAbort    = False
                btnRetry    = False
                btnIgnore   = False
                btnYes      = True
                btnNo       = False
                MsgTimeOut  = False
                Exit Function
            Case 7
                btnOK       = False
                btnCancel   = False
                btnAbort    = False
                btnRetry    = False
                btnIgnore   = False
                btnYes      = False
                btnNo       = True
                MsgTimeOut  = False
                Exit Function
            Case 32000
                btnOK       = False
                btnCancel   = False
                btnAbort    = False
                btnRetry    = False
                btnIgnore   = False
                btnYes      = False
                btnNo       = False
                MsgTimeOut  = True

    Next TimeOutCounter

End Function
```