# VBA Excel macro message box auto close

Tags: vba, excel

I've an Excel macro that runs on opening the file, opens another excel file, refreshes the data, saves and then closes it.

I also have a middle bit (Dim AckTime) that displays a pop up message for second to show  what it's done.

BUT.. Since I set the macro to run on opening the workbook using Public Sub Workbook_Open() the message box pops up but will not close automatically on 1 second anymore.

Can anyone help?

```
Public Sub Workbook_Open()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False

     With Workbooks.Open("\\filename.xlsm")
         ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll 'updates the data
         ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Dashboard").Range("A2").Value = DateTime.Now 
         ' updates this cell with the current time

         Dim AckTime As Integer, InfoBoxWebSearches As Object
         Set InfoBoxWebSearches = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
         AckTime = 1
         Select Case InfoBoxWebSearches.Popup("Updated, saving & closing...", _
             Case 1, -1
         End Select

         .Save
         .Saved = True 'when saved..
         .Close 0 'close the file

     End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Have found that this works just as well

Comment: CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Popup "your message. .", 1, "message header" ' pop up that closes in 1 second

Comment: That was really nice Mike :)

Comment: Does this still work? Microsoft have made a few changes to the ways that one process can close a message box launched by another:   [I posted a long explanation here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4274103/whats-the-best-way-to-display-a-message-box-with-a-timeout-value-from-vba/35139233#35139233)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select Case InfoBoxWebSearches.Popup("Updated, saving & closing...", AckTime)
```

Should be your only error. You just didn't set the wait time.