# Display popup for a time period in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, popup, msgbox

I am trying to generate a popup that closes after a given `WaitTime` in seconds.

I consulted [this](http://www.tushar-mehta.com/publish_train/xl_vba_cases/1023_display_message_for_a_specific_duration.shtml) link and [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x83z1d9f(v=vs.84).aspx) link.

I tried to apply the method from "[VBA Excel macro message box auto close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19008288/vba-excel-macro-message-box-auto-close)"; my code is the following:

```
Sub TestSubroutine()

Dim TemporalBox As Integer
Dim WaitTime As Integer
Dim WScriptShell As Object

Set WScriptShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

WaitTime = 1
TemporalBox = WScriptShell.Popup("The message box will close in 1 second.", _
WaitTime, "File processed")

End Sub
```

The popup is displayed but it never closes after one second.

---

**Edit #1**

Based on @Skip Intro comment, I have updated the code:

```
Sub TestSubroutine()

Dim WaitTime As Integer

WaitTime = 1
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Popup "The message box will close in 1 second.", _
WaitTime, "File processed"

End Sub
```

However this does not solve the original issue, the popup does not close after 1 second.

**Edit #2**

This is the code suggested by @Glitch_Doctor, however it still doesn't work:

```
Sub TestSubroutine()

Dim TemporalBox As Integer
Dim WaitTime As Integer
Dim WScriptShell As Object
Dim test

Set WScriptShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

WaitTime = 1
Select Case TemporalBox = WScriptShell.Popup("The message box will close in 1 second.", _
WaitTime, "File processed")
    Case 1, -1
End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: You can call a popup in one line: `CreateObject("WScript.Shell").popup "This is a message", 1, "This is a header", 0 + 64  '` It only gets complicated if you're trying to capture a response, which I don't think you want if `Wait` = 1 second

Comment: Thank you for the tip. However, this does not solve the original issue, the popup stays open. I have updated the original post.

Comment: That second bit of code works for me. The box appears, then auto closes a second later.

Comment: What OS are you on? I am using Windows 7 and it works according to expectations

Comment: Windows 7 also.

Comment: Hmm, your code, the Edit#1 and the Edit#2 code **all** work for me - `Windows 7` `Excel 2010`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally found a very simple solution - credits to @Orphid, see his answer in the following [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31141775/infobox-popup-refuses-to-close-on-timer-expiration).

I did not solve the specific issue related to my original code, but I managed to create a PopUp that closes after a specified period of time. The code is the following:

```
Sub subClosingPopUp(PauseTime As Integer, Message As String, Title As String)

Dim WScriptShell As Object
Dim ConfigString As String

Set WScriptShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
ConfigString = "mshta.exe vbscript:close(CreateObject(""WScript.Shell"")." & _
               "Popup(""" & Message & """," & PauseTime & ",""" & Title & """))"

WScriptShell.Run ConfigString

End Sub
```

This works just fine.

Comment: Can we make this a Yes/No message box? And automatically make it press no after PauseTime if Yes is not pressed

Comment: This has the advantage of not halting the code execution while the message is displayed

Answer (score 1):

Another approach (if your would not work at all).

Create a new userform named **frm_Popup** and add a label there named **lbl_Message**. Add the following void to userform code:

```
Public Sub StartProcess(iTime As Integer)
    Me.lbl_Message.Caption = "The message box will close in " & iTime & " second(s)."
End Sub
```

then in your module:

```
Sub ShowMessage()
    Dim iTimeToWait As Integer
        iTimeToWait = 2

    With frm_Popup
        .Show False
        Call .StartProcess(iTimeToWait)
    End With

    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:" & iTimeToWait), "HidePopup"
End Sub

Private Sub HidePopup()
    Unload frm_Popup
End Sub
```

Comment: I was thinking of going down the `Application.OnTime` route once I'd finished my report that I'm working on... Well played sir.

Answer (score 0):

You're just missing the `Select Case`:

```
WaitTime = 1
Select Case TemporalBox = WScriptShell.Popup("The message box will close in 1 second.", _
WaitTime, "File processed")
    Case 1, -1
End Select
```

I tested and it works...

Comment: I get a runtime `error 424: object required` when I try that code.

Comment: Sorry I was using your original code, it works with those `Dim`'s

Comment: Weird, do you still get the error with the `Dim`'s in or is the `.Popup` just not closing?

Comment: I don't have any error, the popup is displayed but never closes.

Comment: Only other thing I could think of is that I have a reference turned on that you don't, but the other answer should work. Apart from internet controls which are 100% not relevant to this all I have on is: `Visual Basic For Applications`, `Microsoft Excel 14.0 Object Library`, `OLE Automation`, `Microsoft Office 14.0 Object Library`. Alas I can't differentiate between them. I've just turned them on at some point when I've needed to.

Comment: I have the same references turned on - except I have version 15.0 instead of 14.0, but I have tested the code in another computer with version 15.0 and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Below code work for me, I added a `2-sec` delay before the popup message appears. After `4-sec` it auto disappear. I learn it from Mr. Dinesh Kumar Takyar. He added a `5-sec` delay b4 popup appears. His youtube link
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x1nmqVRrq-Q&list=PLwC8syx0i_6nHjAogOm9m4oGBq40YHkXV&index=4
I think the key issue is you need a delay for the popup timer to work. Maybe the Excel application needs to run for a while b4 the popup appears.

---

```
Option Explicit

Const PopUpTime As Integer = 4
```

```
Sub ShellMessageBox()

Dim MsgBoxWithTimer As Integer

MsgBoxWithTimer=CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Popup("Put your message here", PopUpTime, _
"Notice!", 0)

End Sub
```

```
Sub startTimer()
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"), "ShellMessageBox"
End Sub
```

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

startTimer

End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

The following code works for me:

```
Sub TimeBasedPopUp()

Dim WaitTime As Integer

WaitTime = 1
Select Case CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Popup("The message box will close in 1 second.",_
WaitTime, "MS Excel")
Case 1, -1
```

End Select

End Sub