# Yes/NO Message Box - Automatically press No If there is no response for 5 seconds

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking to automate a workflow of opening a Workbook, running a macro and closing a file

```
//Run a Macro//
ActiveWorkbook.Close
```

But the problem with this is that I can't edit anything if I want to edit something, as it automatically closes the workbook. So I want to pop-up a Yes/No Message Box asking if I want to close the file. If there is no response it should automatically close(Press Yes).

```
/*Run a Macro*/
Close:= MsgBox, "Do you want to Close the File?", vbYesNo

/*Wait for 5 seconds for Response. If no response, automatically click Yes.*/

If Close = vbYes Then
   ActiveWorkbook.Close
Else
   'Don't Close
End If
```

P.S: Please do let me know if there is any simpler way to this.

**Edit #1:**

Thank you for the link below. I did find the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40631009/display-popup-for-a-time-period-in-excel) provided below useful, but it doesn't not satisy below points

1. it is not a Yes/No popup.
2. it doesn't click the Yes or Ok after 5 seconds. It just unloads the popup I tried this method using
3. Userforms too. Using the Application.OnTime Now +
   TimeValue("00:00:05"), "Test" function. But even that is not
   desirable. Even if I click no the userform still runs the "Test"
   Sub.

Comment: Yes it is possible but for that do not use `MsgBox`. Use a Userform

Comment: Do you have any Example? I could really use some help.

Comment: Example: On Userform activation: Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"), "NoResponse"... Make a module that will Unload your userform.