# Background code to see how long the spreadsheet has been open

Tags: excel, vba

I want to evaluate how long the spreadsheet has been open and once it hits a certain time (say an hour), warn the user that it will automatically close in 15 mins.

I have a tab called Reference where I can put auto-open code to log when they opened it but I want the spreadsheet to check unprompted at certain intervals how long the sheet has been open.

I want to force a close where a user has accidentally left a spreadsheet open so it's important it isn't assessed based on user input.
Note - I don't care if they lose work, I just want to close the spreadsheet.

Comment: Have a look at Application.OnTime: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Application.OnTime  Put it into Workbook.Open-Trigger

Comment: Thank you so much! I had no idea this was a thing. It definitely sounds like that will work.

Comment: FunThomas, if you post this as an answer, I can accept it. Currently all I can do is upvote it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To schedule the call of a routine, use `Application.OnTime`. To ensure that the routine is scheduled to "one hour after opening", create a Workbook-Open sub (in ThisWorkbook-Module) and put something like this into it:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.OnTime DateAdd("h", 1, Now), "InformUser"
End Sub
```

This will call the Sub `InformUser` one hour after the Workbook was opened. In this routine you could add another call to `OnTime`. However, you need to be a little bit careful how to inform the user. If you simple use `MsgBox` but the user is not reacting to that, the MsgBox-Window stays active and as it is a modal window, the code will not continue to run and the `OnTime`-procedure will never be triggered. It's not easy to create a MsgBox with a TimeOut (see [Display a message box with a timeout value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4274103/display-a-message-box-with-a-timeout-value)), so maybe create a simple form and show it Non-Modal.

```
Sub InformUser()
    InfoForm.Show modal:=False
    Application.OnTime DateAdd("n", 15, Now), "ShutDown"   ' "n": Minutes ("m" stands for months)
End Sub

Sub ShutDown
    ThisWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True   ' Or "False" if you don't want to save - use on your own risk...
End Sub
```

Comment: Afaik `OnTime` 's procedure argument should be a string, here e.g.  `Application.OnTime DateAdd("n", 15, Now), "InformUser"`

Comment: @T.M. Good catch, have corrected the code.